# java Update a .XML file from a .txt file

Tags: java, xml

I have a "achat.txt" file on every purchase with a line separated by commas information.

```
 Jean Charles, 3214324565, 321, 2
 Yvan Richard, 5435435545, 321, 1
 Yvette Gagnon, 4324324243, 1, 12
```

I have a inventaire.XML file my inventory.

Code :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
 <inventaire>
 <produit code="1" prix="432.00" quantité= "43" />
 <produit code="32" prix="32.00" quantité= "100"  />
 <produit code="321" prix="31.00" quantité= "200"  />
 </inventaire>
```

I have to write a program in which DOM updates the inventory taking into account the "achats.txt" .The file update only applies to the attribute "code" and "quantity" of "achats.txt" file.

I managed to read the "achats.txt" file in java program.

Code :

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;  
import java.io.FileReader;  
import java.io.IOException;  
import java.io.BufferedReader;  
import java.io.FileReader;  
import java.io.IOException; 




public class Affiche {     // On créer une classe "Affiche"
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {  
            FileReader fichier = new FileReader("achats.txt");        
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fichier);   
            String ligne = null;  
            while ((ligne = br.readLine()) != null) {            
String str[] =ligne.split(",");  
System.out.println (str[2] =","+str[3]);                          


 }
 fichier.close()
 }
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
DocumentBuilder parser = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = parser.parse("inventaire.xml");
Element racine = doc.getDocumentElement();
NodeList nl = racine.getElementsByTagName("produit");        
for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); ++i) {              
 Element produit = (Element) nl.item(i);        
 }
```

I don't know how to create an array of string that will contain the variables achats.txt file. I don't know either how to get the "code" and "quantity" attribute then subtract the inventaire.xml file.
Thank you for your help

Comment: Which transformation do you want to do? Which is the meaning of the txt columns? Is the last column the quantity and should be added to the existing "quantité"? And about the creation of the array, I would use an `Arraylist`.

Answer (score 0):

An arraylist would just be fantastic. I think @Bruno may try testing java's containers a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could take a gander at the classes for the purpose in Guava.

http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Files.html#readLines(java.io.File,%20java.nio.charset.Charset)

is a method you can call, passing it a file, and receive in return a list of Strings, one per line.